# How to find number of memory accesses

Tags: memory, memcached, memory-management, sar

Can anybody tell me a unix command that can be used to find the number of memory accesses that took place in a given interval. vmstat, top and sar only give the amount of physical memory space occupied/available .. But do not give the number of memory of accesses in a given interval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, such a feature would almost certainly require hardware support at a very low level (e.g. a counter of some sort that monitors memory bus activity).
I don't think such support is available for the common architectures supported by
Unix or Linux, so I'm going to go out on a limb and say that no such Unix command exists.

The situation is somewhat different when considering memory in units of *pages*, 
because most architectures that support virtual memory have dedicated MMU hardware
which operates at that level of granularity, and can be accessed by the operating
system.  But as far as I know, the sorts of counter data you'd get from the MMU would
represent events like page faults, allocations, and releases, rather than individual
reads or writes.